# How to make directory format backup

Tags: postgresql, backup, database-backups, pg-dump

Creating backup in directory format using

```
pg_dump -f "sba" -Fdirectory --jobs=32 --verbose sba
```

throws error

```
pg_dump: error: could not stat file "sba/282168.data.gz": value too large
```

How to create backup in format from which tables can selectively restored?

This file size is 6.2 GB in NTFS. Was backup created successfully? Is this only informational message?

Server is Postgres 12 running in Debian Linux 10 under WSL

Client is pg_dump from Postgres 15 running in Windows 11